# How to remove KDE leftovers without breaking anything

Tags: kde, cinnamon, 18.10

I made the mistake to install KDE Plasma to check it out after being unsatisfied with gnome. Finally I found Cinnamon was more to my liking. So that's what I'm using now.

My question is how to remove all the KDE leftovers? I already used some commands I found online to remove the bulk of it but there are still applications like KDE Settings as well as a ton of results for kde under installed in Synaptics.

However I know that some applications might require some KDE libraries.

So my question is, can I remove everything with a kde in it in Synaptics and then install some KDE libraries to make sure any KDE-based applications I really need (for e.g. KMyMoney) will run?

Comment: It's a bit late now, but I would have just removed whatever you installed , then followed with `sudo apt autoremove` to get rid of added dependencies automatically.  If you'd forgotten what you installed (esp. if not done by command and thus in `history), I would have followed apt logs.

Comment: Given that you have applications that need `kde` dependencies, I'd suggest being very cautious. Use the terminal and run `apt purge -s package_name` to get an idea of what else will be removed each time you attempt to purge anything. Also, if you aren't short on space, it maybe safer to leave things well alone.

Comment: yes I've done that already (re: what I installed - plasma) but I still have a ton of kde stuff installed and I know some of it is not needed, otherwise why would I still have KDE Settings? I would have thought removing plasma would have gotten ridden of that

Comment: Getting rid of a metapackage will not necessarily remove the packages installed by it.